# Using Link in React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am following a tutorial that uses the older version of React Router. I have it all updated and working except for the following bit of code:

```
{this.props.books.map((b, i) => <tr key={i}>
    <td>{b.title}</td>
    <td><Link to={`/books/${b.id}`}>View</Link></td>
</tr>)}
```

I am getting an error on the `` <Link to={`/books/${b.id}`}>View</Link> ``.

There are a few different errors related to that one line. The first error is:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Book`.
>       in Book (created by Connect(Book))
>       in Connect(Book) (created by Route)
>       in Route
>       in div
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in BrowserRouter
>       in Provider

What is the problem with this line and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Check link import statement from react-dom.

Comment: @karaxuna That was indeed my problem. I originally had `import { Link } from 'react-router'` instead of `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was because I had `import { Link } from 'react-router'` instead of `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`. Once I made the change everything worked properly. Thanks to karaxuna for figuring that out.

selmansamet was also correct that backticks were needed, but was not really the source of the problem. The original code did have backticks, but I changed them to single quotes to see if that would fix the problem. It did not.

Answer (score 1):

In JSX, strings must be in **backtick** quotes, not double or single quotes.

```
<td><Link to={`/books/${b.id}`}>View</Link></td>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried changing them to backticks and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try this: <td><Link to={'/books/$`{b.id}`'}>View</Link></td>